# Disable "left swipe gesture / app switching" in Windows 10 on Surface 3

Tags: windows-10, alt-tab, gestures

Is it possible to disable 'left swipe / gesture' or 'App Switching' in tablet mode on a Surface 3? I am Left Handed and whenever I use the 'Pen' in One note, my palm rests on the left hand edge and opens up the App Switch view constantly. I have disabled tablet mode, disabled the keyboard, disabled Task View, had to move the task bar to the right so I don't hit the start button with my left hand, got 'Left Handed' set up in Device Settings for the pen, disabled Arrange Windows under Multi Tasking - any other left handers got this issue and fixed it? This is only an issue for me in tablet mode when using the pen in One note. Many thanks